# Parse URL in Azure functions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, urlparse

Am learning how to use Azure functions and so new to it. I have a httptrigger Azure function written in NodeJs. I am thinking of a logic on how to parse data from httptrigger function URL and use it in my code. Would like some suggestions on this?

In simple words,

1. I would like to know how to pass a string parameter to the functions URL.
2. Then parse the string from the URL and use it in my code logic.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DanielNetzer added some more info on this

Comment: Can you add an example of that data? Did you checked Azure docs for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See an example in [Customize the HTTP endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#customize-the-http-endpoint).

You can define `route` in `function.json`:

```
"route": "products/{category:alpha}/{id:int?}"
```

and then get URL parts from `context`:

```
var category = context.bindingData.category;
var id = context.bindingData.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

Mikhail's answer works if you want to put the "parameters" in the base part of the URL separated by `/`. However, if you wanted to use query parameter syntax (e.g. `http://myEndpoint?myParam1=10&myParam2=hello`), those show up already parsed in `context.req.query`